# Why gdb shows different addresses in RIP-relative mode from absolute address?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, disassembly, relative-addressing

Having this in `c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int x;
int main(){
    printf("eneter x\n");   
    scanf("%i",&x);
    printf("you enetered: %i\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

in gdb:

```
starti
disas main

0x0000555555555155 <+0>:    push   %rbp
   0x0000555555555156 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000555555555159 <+4>: lea    0xea4(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555556004
   0x0000555555555160 <+11>:    callq  0x555555555030 <puts@plt>
   0x0000555555555165 <+16>:    lea    0x2ed8(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555558044 <x>
   0x000055555555516c <+23>:    lea    0xe9a(%rip),%rdi        # 0x55555555600d
   0x0000555555555173 <+30>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555178 <+35>:    callq  0x555555555050 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
   0x000055555555517d <+40>:    mov    0x2ec1(%rip),%eax        # 0x555555558044 <x>
   0x0000555555555183 <+46>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x0000555555555185 <+48>:    lea    0xe84(%rip),%rdi        # 0x555555556010
   0x000055555555518c <+55>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555191 <+60>:    callq  0x555555555040 <printf@plt>
   0x0000555555555196 <+65>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555519b <+70>:    pop    %rbp
   0x000055555555519c <+71>:    retq
```

here the relative address of `x` variable is `$rip+0x2ed8` (from instruction `lea    0x2ed8(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555558044`). But as you can see in the comment `#`, the *absolute* address is `0x555555558044`. Ok will I get that address when try to read from the relative one? Lets see:

```
x $rip+0x2ed8
0x555555558055: 0x00000000
```

nop - relative address did not use the absolute address, where the `x` var is really stored (`0x555555558055` != `0x555555558044`) the difference is 17 bytes. Is it the number of bytes of the instruction itself (`lea` + operands)? I do not know, but do not think so. So why does relative and absolute addressing differ in gdb?

PS, generated assembly:

```
.file   "a.c"
    .comm   x,4,4
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "eneter x"
.LC1:
    .string "%i"
.LC2:
    .string "you enetered: %i\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
# a.c:5:    printf("eneter x\n");   
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi    #,
    call    puts@PLT    #
# a.c:6:    scanf("%i",&x);
    leaq    x(%rip), %rsi   #,
    leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rdi    #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    __isoc99_scanf@PLT  #
# a.c:7:    printf("you enetered: %i\n", x);
    movl    x(%rip), %eax   # x, x.0_1
    movl    %eax, %esi  # x.0_1,
    leaq    .LC2(%rip), %rdi    #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    printf@PLT  #
# a.c:8:    return 0;
    movl    $0, %eax    #, _6
# a.c:9: }
    popq    %rbp    #
    ret 
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Here, the RIP-relative mode *is* used:

```
# a.c:6:    scanf("%i",&x);
    leaq    x(%rip), %rsi   #,
```

where the `x` is position of the `x` symbol. But in comments, someone said, that `$rip+0x2ed8` is not the same, and the offset `0x2ed8` does not lead to the address of the `x`. But why those two differ? but should be RIP-relative mode addressing and both should gain the same offset (and thus address).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215875/discussion-on-question-by-autistic456-why-gdb-shows-different-addresses-in-rip-r).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   0x0000555555555165 <+16>:    lea    0x2ed8(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555558044 <x>
   0x000055555555516c <+23>:    lea    0xe9a(%rip),%rdi        # 0x55555555600d
```

A RIP relative address in an instruction is relative to the address just *after* the current instruction (i.e. the address of the instruction plus the size of the instruction, or the address of the following instruction).  This is because when the instruction has been loaded into the processor, the RIP register is advanced by the size of the current instruction just before it is executed. (At least that is the model that is followed even though modern processors use all sorts of tricks behind the scenes to speed up execution.) (Note: The above is true for several CPU architectures, including x86 variants, but some other CPU architectures differ in the point from which PC-relative addresses are measured<sup>1</sup>.)

The first instruction above is at address 0x555555555165 and the following instruction is at address 0x55555555516c (the instruction is 7 bytes long). In the first instruction, the RIP relative address `0x2ed8(%rip)` refers to 0x2ed8 + 0x000055555555516c = 0x555555558044.

Note that if you set a breakpoint on an instruction in a debugger and show the registers when the breakpoint is reached, RIP will point to the current instruction, not the next one, because the current instruction is not being executed yet.

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to Peter Cordes for details about PC-relative addressing for ARM and RISC-V CPU architectures.

Comment: If I did not know the source, how can I determine size of next instruction

Comment: @autistic456 x86 instructions are variable length and depend on the addressing modes. You need to consult an instruction set reference for the processor to determine the size of an instruction. I have changed my answer to clarify exactly when the RIP register is updated.

Comment: Abbot, *RIP will point to the current instruction, not the next one, because the current instruction is not being executed yet*, `rip` in debugger shows current instruction, because debugger shows *not yet executed*, however in program flow, the "real" `rip` shows next instruction, because the executes inline. Well then the rip in debugger is misleading, since I understand the stops before execution, but I have now 2 `rip` references that has 2 meanings (the debuger `rip` and the "real" - executable `rip`), is it a feature or bug?

Comment: @autistic456 Basically, the RIP register tells the processor where to load and execute the next instruction from. It gets updated automatically after loading the instruction but before it executes the instruction. So during execution of the instruction, RIP is already pointing to the next instruction in memory. (Of course, certain instructions will then alter RIP to point somewhere else, to perform branching etc.) It's a feature of the x86 and many other processors that the instruction pointer is updated before execution of the instruction.

Comment: @autiscic456 The debugger RIP and the real RIP are the same. At a breakpoint, the RIP has the value resulting from the previously executed instruction, just like the other registers.

Comment: yes, I understand (there are 2 events - loading, executing; only after loading but before executing gets the rip altered), but since gdb only loads in each steps, and after that they execute, the rip can be confusing in gdb in comparison with real flow of program. That's only the point

Comment: @autistic456 Yes, it's confusing at first, but most processors do it like that. (I can't think of any that don't, off the top of my head.) It's easier to deal with for processors that use fixed size instructions!

Comment: fixed sized instruction would be waste or? And it would only has to be of the size of the biggest instruction to fit. Which means the for example `movabs $symbol, %reg`, would be 10 bytes long, since one of the operan would be address of the symbol and then all instructions would have to be at least 10 bytes long. I do not think this is the best solution

Comment: It's common for RISC processor designs to use a fixed instruction length, although some of them later introduced special modes to execute compacted instruction sets (e.g. ARM "Thumb" mode) to save memory.

Comment: ARM PC-relative addressing is relative to 2 instructions after the current one, IIRC.  Original ARM was a 3-stage pipeline or something like that, and apparently it was more convenient to build the first-gen hardware that way.  Also, RISC-V does relative branches relative to the branch instruction's start address, not the end.  So there are exceptions to the common way of going relative to the end of the instruction.  It's common because the fetch or decode stage just did the address math to get ready for the next instruction, in parallel with decoding to find out that this is a PC reference.

Comment: @autistic456: ISAs with fixed-width instructions need multiple instructions to construct large constants, or they have to load them from memory.  The usual instruction width for 32-bit / 64-bit fixed-width ISAs is 4 bytes.  AArch64 has a clever way to encode immediate constants, allowing for repeating bit-patterns of various lengths, so for example `and x0, x1, 0x5555555555555555` fits in one instruction.  For actual addresses, modern ISAs calculate them with PC-relative stuff to avoid needing 64-bit constants.  (x86-64 does this too, with `lea symbol(%rip), %reg`, not movabs.)

Comment: @autistic456: so yes, x86-64 has a code-density advantage when you can't avoid 64-bit immediate constants, and often in general if you can use small instructions, but it pays dearly for it in decode power and performance.  That's why x86-64 needs a uop cache for the front-end to keep up with the back-end.  Fixed-width instructions, or at least easy-to-decode variable length like Thumb2, make much more sense.  You'd never design x86-64 machine code exactly the way it is, if starting over from scratch.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. I've added a note about other CPU architectures.